# US Dollar Index: a) where are long term charts;  also b) is it available on Google Finance by any chance?

Tags: online-data-source, historical-data, usd-us-dollar

Apparently the U.S. Dollar Index (DXY) has been around for ages since 1973, as this [site points out](http://www.fxtrademaker.com/usdx.htm).  Also, I'm able to find it on [Market Watch](http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/index/dxy), albeit with only a 5 year graphing option.

I'm trying to find a longer charting place where I can also compare it to the S&P500 index.  (If you compare it against the S&P500 over 5 years I think the graph is very interesting, i.e. the Beta appears to be almost minus one, i.e. inversely correlated to the market).

Also, secondly, as I use the stock list / charting capabilities of Google Finance, do you know of what index to use there?   If you have a better charting / stock list site, please let me know, I'm not stuck on Google Finance, just want to see major indexes and stocks in one place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

a) the quick answer to your correlation is quantitative easing. basically the central bank has been devaluing the US dollar, making the prices of all goods increase (including stocks.)

the stock market appear to have recovered from 2009 lows but its mainly an illusion. anyway the QE packages are very known

when the correlation is not there, that means other meaningful things are happening such as better corporate earnings and real growth.

b) the thinkorswim platform has charts for dollar futures, symbol /dx

Comment: Thanks CQM.  It's always a bit confusing how much inflation is going on, in terms of the measurements given by the U.S. Govt.  I think how exports are impacted is also a factor in the inverse relationship, perhaps especially since many companies in the S&P500 have international business.  Thoughts/comments?

Comment: This is not untrue, I would say roughly 30% of the S&P500 is related to nonUS-source growth

Comment: BTW, I didn't see a place on Thinkorswim for looking at a chart (I'm not a member).  Do you know of an "external" link where I can? Thanks.

Comment: you have to have an account with thinkorswim and download their platform. I think its still free, you need a funded account (with min 2K) for live quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  Can you do me a favor and tell me how many years back it shows the dx index ... is it more than 5 years?

Comment: I can see back to Jan 1st 2002.